# How to share data between two python scripts both running?

Tags: python, database, automation, queue

I'm working on an automated posting script, I want this script to post to my blog every 1 hour(Script 1), and using another script I will define post objects(Script 2).
So for example I want to create 15 posts using Script 2 but I don't want to post all 15 at the same time, I want Script 1 to check every hour if there's a post available, post 1 of the 15s.
So they are 2 different scripts, both running separately, but how can I add created post by Script 2 to the queue of Script 1?
one of the ways that got into my head was using the SQL database, Script 2 add created post as the last item of the database, and Script 1 read database every hour and pick the first item and then delete it from the queue.

```
  Script 1 pick and delete first item ----->  ---- Post 0 ----
                                              ---- Post 1 ----
                                              ---- Post 2 ----
                                              ---- Post 3 ----
  Script 2 add created post as last item -->  ---- Post 4 ----
```

But this solution seems a bit hard, is there any simpler and more stable way?

also, I want it to save and keep data if scripts restarted or server shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to have one more column in DB which says `posted`, which set to `False` by default. Once script 1 posts it, it updates the column `posted` to `True`.

While querying the DB you can write something like

```
Select top 1 * 
from post 
where posted = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `redis` queue and use `push`, `pop` methods.
this is better than other db.